# Overflow content not scrolling correctly with jquery-scrollify. Content overlapping. Different results with different page widths

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I am trying to build a personal website which utilized the jQuery-scrollify tool to scroll through the several sections of my site. However, regardless of the settings I use, I cannot get the page to consistently scroll correctly. If the screen is too small or too big then the last section won't scroll to show the overflow content, but somewhere in the middle the content does scroll correctly. I've toggled the setHeight property which seems to address some of the overflowing scrolling issues but then causes certain sections to overlap at different heights.

I've been working on this for the better part of two days trying to alternate different setting and change the layout of the page to fit with the tool but haven't made any progress.
The content of the [page](http://**/) is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>**</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="img/icons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="img/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="img/icons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js?v=234651"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css?v=234651">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-header">
    <div>
        <h1>**</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Full Stack Software Developer</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="about">
        <h3>About Me</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#bio" data-name="2">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#education" data-name="3">Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="#experience" data-name="4">Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
        <h3>Find Me</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/**/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/**" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:**@gmail.com">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="page" id="banner">
        <img src="img/fun_me_cropped.jpg" class="banner-img">
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="bio">
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="education">
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="experience">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //different scrollify options based on screen size
        const scroll_opts = [
            {
                section: '.page',
                offset: -150,
//                scrollbars: false,
                setHeights: false
            },
            {
                section: '.page',
                offset: 0,
                scrollbars: false,
                setHeights: false
            }
        ];

        //initialize scrollify based on document width
        if (document.body.clientWidth > 600) {
            $.scrollify(scroll_opts[0]);
        } else {
            $.scrollify(scroll_opts[1]);
        }

        //override default linking to use scrollify move method
        $('.about a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.scrollify.move('#' + $(this).attr('data-name'));
        });

        //prevent excessive processing on resize $(window).resize(function() {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if (this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
            this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
            }, 500);
        });

        $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function () {
            if (document.body.clientWidth > 600) {
                $.scrollify.setOptions(scroll_opts[0]);
            } else {
                $.scrollify.setOptions(scroll_opts[1]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited - This is apparently a popular post, and I realized this has some personal info in it, which probably isn't best suited for a SO post. So I cleaned up the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got collapsed content within your sections. This happens when content is floated inside a container that isn't cleared.

Comment: I don't have any floated content. The containing "page" divs are all the correct size and contain all their content, but the scrolling is nonetheless acting sporadic.

Comment: The code looks fine. Maybe try enabling scroll bars in the Scrollify options and seeing if that makes a difference.